# Obtaining the correct result using recursion in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, logic

I've created a data structure to represent an n * n * n cube, in this specific case it's a 4*4*4 cube. For the purpose of debugging, I'd like to implement a method which prints the cube to stdout. The result should be 4 layers, each of them consisting of a 4x4 area.

Since I'm learning Scala, I want to do it in a "functional manner" and came up with a recursive solution. The `drawCube` method "loops" over all layers, the `drawLayer` method loops over the lines of a layer and the `drawLine` method is responsible for a single line.

- Each line should begin and end with a slash
- The layers should be separated by a line of dashes

The code:

```
    def drawCube = {
     val n = cube.sidelength
     val nl = sys.props("line.separator")
     val border = " -" * (n * 2 -1)

     def drawLine(acc: String, x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): String = {
      if(x < n) drawLine(acc + getField(x, y, z), x + 1, y, z) else <PosA> + acc + "/" + nl
     }
     def drawLayer(acc: String, y: Int, z: Int): String = {
      if(z >= 0) drawLayer(<PosB> + drawLine(acc, 0, y, z), y, z - 1) else acc + border + nl
     }
     def drawCube(acc: String, y: Int): String = {
      if(y < n) drawCube(drawLayer(acc, y, n - 1), y + 1) else border + nl + acc
     }
     def getField(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = {
      // returns a string representation of a specific field from the cube
      // in the following example, it's just a dot for the sake of simplicity
      // in a 4x4x4 cube, the range of x, y and z is from 0 to 3
     }
     println(drawCube("", 0))
    }
```

Regardless of whether I'm putting an additional "/" into *Position A* or *Position B* (see placeholders above), I'm always getting the following result:

```
 - - - - - - -
//////////////// .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 - - - - - - -
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 - - - - - - -
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 - - - - - - -
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 .  .  .  . /
 - - - - - - -
```

As you can see, everything works fine, except of the the leading slashes, which are all printed at once instead of the beginning of a line. Why is that? What would be the correct position? Perhaps I spent too much time with it, but I can't see the problem right now.Thanks.

*edit: you may have noticed that the stop condition of the drawLayer method looks slightly different compared to the other two. That has to do with a transformation of the coordinate system, the origin should be displayed at the top left front corner. But I don't think that's the issue here, the fields are displayed at the correct positions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great advantage of the functional style is that you can test the smaller methods individually. Try testing `drawLine` on its own, or replacing `drawLine` with something simpler and testing `drawLayer`. I would recommend avoiding the accumulator until you have the basic functionality working - a simple `0 until n map {drawLine(_, y, z)} mkString` has less to go wrong.

To answer your specific question, the accumulator is always the *complete* current drawing of the cube, as is the return value from any of your functions. So you can't ever do `"/" + acc` or `"/" + drawSomething()` as this will always add the "/" onto the very start. Instead you need to add the "/" onto the *end* of `acc`, *before* calling `drawLine`. i.e. `drawLayer` should be defined as:

```
def drawLayer(acc: String, y: Int, z: Int): String =
  if(z >= 0) drawLayer(drawLine(acc + "/", 0, y, z), y, z - 1) else acc + "-" + "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer. Not only the solution, but also your hints.